# Multiple replacemenst with a single RegEx in. Net

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Is it possible to replace a different characters based on different matching patterns using a single RegEx. For example, if you have the following string:

iOoi9345

Can you write a single regular expression to say replace any i's by 1 and any O's, whether small or capital letter by a 0 (zero) on the entire string or does it need to be done in multiple steps?

The reason I'm asking this is that I'm building a UI and I want to know if it is sufficient to provide a couple of textboxes, one for the pattern(s) and one for the values to replace it with or do I have to provide list where multiple RegEx will be defined each dealing with its own use case.

I appreciate the feedback.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a mapping dictionary and define your replacement...

```
// say this is your input, to define the replacement convention
string uiTextBox = "i:1, I:1, o:0, O:0";

string[] conversion = uiTextBox.Split(new char[] { ',' });
IDictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (string rule in conversion)
{
    string[] r = rule.Trim().Split(new char[] { ':' });
    map.Add(r[0], r[1]);
}

/* map would contain, {"{i, 1}, {I, 1}, {o, 0}, {O, 0}"} */
var str = "aiAIboBOCDEF";
var regex = new Regex(String.Join("|", map.Keys));
var replaceStr = regex.Replace(str, m => map[m.Value]);
```

Comment: Same comment as below but just can't have anything hardcoded as I need to leave it flexible enough so that it can be changed via UI.

Comment: Please check my updated answer, if your input defines the rule, you can replace them using a single regex... not sure if this is going to help?

Comment: I've gone ahead with a recursive function as mentioned below and is working very nicely and it will allow me to do a lot more with it (replace, split, substring and more) but what you have provided would definitely work with my original question, so I'll award you the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

You can't specify conditional substitutions using .NET Regex.

But you could use [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx) with a delegate:

```
Regex.Replace("iOoi9345", "i|[Oo]", m => m.Value == "i" ? "1" : "0")
```

Comment: That's good to know but as this is just one of my use cases, it probably won't be suitable and I'll probably have to provide a list to define multiple regex or provide a simple custom script language and use recursion. Something like Replace(Replace(myvalue,O,0),i,1) and use recursion.